# Why is drawString not appearing in the JFrame GUI?

Tags: java, jframe

```
package me.tykutcher.text.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class textGui {

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("String", 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(1080, 1080);
        frame.setTitle("Loading... ");  
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }



}
```

I don't understand why the drawSting("String); is not showing up in the GUI. I have done this before and I cannot remember what I am missing as well as cannot find any solutions online.

Comment: Add `@Override` above `paint` and see what you get

Comment: @MadProgrammer why would he override if he’s not extending anything

Comment: @JacobB. Precisely

Comment: He should be making a class that extends JPanel or JFrame or something, AND THEN add the paint() or paintComponent() methods into it with an override.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take a step back and re-check the available tutorials, starting with [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to better understand how painting actually works.

Your basic problem is, you seem to have a notation of "code by magic".  Ask yourself, what is going to call your `paint` method (and how)?

Basically, in order to perform custom painting, you need to extend from a `JComponent` based class, override it's `paintComponent` method (calling `super.paintComponent` to maintain the paint chain) and perform your custom painting.

You then need to attach this component to something which is actually displayed on the screen

[image: Magic]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawString("String", 50, 50);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yeah this is what I was saying in above comments  +1 my dude

Comment: @JacobB. My point was to try and make the OP realise that  just having a `paint` method, doesn't make something paintable - to many questions lately which could be fixed by using `@Override` to verify their own intent ;)

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. I love the passive aggressive teaching idea  ill have to use that

Comment: @JacobB. I have a spare brick if you'd like to smack your head against it 